# Why is friction positive in this solution?

Tags: work, friction, kinetic-theory

[image]

[image]

According to the solution, the work of kinetic friction is positive, but doesn't the friction force always go negative to the displacement, making the work by friction negative? Why is friction positive in the solution.

The values used in the question and solution are different, but solve for the same thing in question (a).

Comment: See [Bob's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/791151/349627) for a good response, but when you say:

>"but doesn't the friction force always go negative to the displacement[?]"

The kinetic friction force is actually directed opposite to the direction of velocity (i.e., the change in displacement) rather than displacement itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to the solution, the work of kinetic friction is positive,

That's not what is says.

Move the friction work and the work done by the spring to the left side of the equation. Then the left side of the equation becomes the net work done on the block and the right side becomes the change in kinetic energy of the block, per the work energy theorem. The work done by the applied force is positive while the work done by friction and spring forces are negative.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it